# Unit testings Laravel 4 with PHPUnit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-4, composer-php

I've added `"phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"` to the `require-dev` section of `composer.json` and ran `composer install`. Unfortunately, when I run `vendor/bin/phpunit` from the root of my Larvel 4 project, I get the following error:

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit
vendor/bin/phpunit: line 1: ../phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit: No such file or directory
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you think you can run it that way?

Comment: Have you even verified the file is there?  You should have done a composer update.  Otherwise that is right, except for the file not being there.

Comment: Assuming that the `../phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit` refers to `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit` then yes, the file is there.

I just ran it from the vendor/bin folder (assuming the relative path was messing things up), and I'm now getting this guy:

`PHPUnit 3.7.24 by Sebastian Bergmann.
    
    Usage: phpunit [switches] UnitTest [UnitTest.php]
           phpunit [switches] <directory>`

Also, I'm running on a ubuntu VM in Windows 7, using Git Bash to ssh into the VM. I feel like I'm getting closer. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the install command with the `--dev` flag

```
$ composer install --dev
```

Since you already run a `composer install`, just run a `composer update` now. The update command assumes you are in a dev environment and download your dev dependencies without any flags.

To make sure your composer is up to date, run `composer self-update` before this commands.